# Not to read hidden sheets of xlsb file using XSSFBReader in apache poi

Tags: excel, apache-poi, saxparser, xssf

I am reading xlsb file using XSSFBReader class from apache poi library. I do not find any way to read only visible sheets of xlsb file. Currently, code reads all the sheets of xlsb file.
How to read only visible sheets using XSSFBReader ?

```
    pkg = OPCPackage.open(filename, PackageAccess.READ_WRITE);
    XSSFBReader r = new XSSFBReader(pkg);
    XSSFBReader.SheetIterator it = (XSSFBReader.SheetIterator) r.getSheetsData();
    while (it.hasNext()) { //This iterates over all sheets of xlsb file
                
                InputStream is = it.next();
                String sheetName = it.getSheetName();
                //some processing
    }
```